# Day listing in colorbox or ctools popup

Tags: 7, views

I am using calendar module and using calendar widget to show in front-end. Views has option to link title with colorbox popup. Here comes my obstacle I have multiple events in a day. When user clicks on the date at calendar widget it should popup to provide the day event listings in popup. How can I achieve this?

[image: Calendar Widget]

[image: Event listing for Day]

Comment: You can rewrite the title output when editing the view (click on the field in the **Fields area** and then **Rewrite results**). Something like this: `<a href="/path-to-day-events" class="colorbox" title="Day events">[title]</a>`. You can place in this tag any other colorbox attributes. 

I think that the day path can also be written using patterns from the view.

Comment: @OanaHulpoi : I have update the link for title, achieved using views. But how can i achieve same on Calendar widget (Refer first image) link date with popup to provide the day event listings.